# Objective-c adding to array same instance with different properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying the following code to create an instance, assign properties, add to array.
Then, assigning new properties and adding again.
However array will contain 2 identical objects (equal to the second one added). The class Message simply has several (nonatomic, retain) NSStrings/Integer properties.
This probably has something to do with my understanding of pointer, can someone explain?

```
    self.messages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    Message *m=[[Message alloc]init];
    m.cb=@"2402";
    m.ck=1001;
    m.msg=@"as";
     [self.messages addObject:m];

    m.cb=@"2422";
    m.ck=1002;
    m.msg=@"aadfsdsdfdssdklsdflkh";
    [self.messages addObject:m];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.messages);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add an object to an array, it does **not** add a copy of the object to the array, but instead just a reference to it.  If you want two different objects, then you need to create two different objects instead of re-using the same one (or, as @Brendon points out, create a copy when you add it to your array).

To fix your example, the most common technique would be to add the following line right before you start modifying the properties for the second object:

```
m=[[Message alloc]init];
```

Or, use a second pointer and object instead of reusing `m`.

**EDIT:**
To add a copy, change `[self.messages addObject:m];` to `[self.messages addObject:[m copy]];`, assuming that the `Message` class conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: how would I create a copy on adding to array?

Comment: you mean `[self.messages addObject:[m copy]];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after executing the posted code `self.messages` contains the `Message` object twice, at indexes 0 and 1. That's not a problem, though. Arrays can contain any object, even themselves.

It seems that you want two distict objects, so you would just create a second `Message`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement the NSCopy protocol — as mentioned by lnafziger — or just create new instances quite easily in a for loop.

> «Two or more, use a for»
>   — Edsger W. Dijkstra

```
self.messages=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *dataArray = @[ @{@"cb": @"2402", @"ck": @(1001), @"msg": @"as"}, 
                        @{@"cb": @"2422", @"ck": @(1002), @"msg": @"aadfsdsdfdssdklsdflkh"}
                      ];


for(NSDictionary *data in dataArray) {
    Message *m=[[Message alloc] init];
    m.cb = data[@"cb"];
    m.ck = [data[@"ck"] integerValue];
    m.msg = data[@"msg"];
    [self.messages addObject:m];
}
```